# Segmentation fault in Collatz Conjecture program in C

Tags: c

I was running this program (for the [Collatz Conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture)) and I got a segmentation fault at line 33, but line 33 is just a `}` at the end of a block. I don't know if it's a stack problem.  Can you help?

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int x,y,temp;
    int  maximum_cycle[MAX_NUMERO];
    scanf("%d",&x);
    scanf("\n%d",&y);
    if (x>y){
        temp=x;
        x=y;
        y=temp;
    }
    hallarNumeroCiclo(x,y,&maximum_cycle[MAX_NUMERO]);
    printf("\n%d %d %d\n",x,y,Maximo(x,y,&maximum_cycle[MAX_NUMERO]));
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

hallarNumeroCiclo(int x,int y,int *maximum_cycle[MAX_NUMERO]){
    int k,n;    
    for (n=0;(x < y) ;--y){
        for(k=y;k!=1;){
            if ((k % 2) ==0)
            {
                k/=2;
                n+=1;
            }
            else if ((k%2)==1)
            {
                k = 3*k+1;
                n+=1;
            }
            if (k==1) {
                n+=1;
            /*this is the line where the error occurs, the next bracket */ 
            }
        }
        *maximum_cycle[y-x]=n;
    }    
}

int Maximo(int x, int y,int *maximum_cycle[MAX_NUMERO]){
    int i;
    int maximo =0;
    for(i=0;(i>(y-x));i++){
        if (*maximum_cycle[i]>maximo){
            maximo=*maximum_cycle[i];
        }
    }
    return maximo;
}
```

Comment: Your compiler should be giving you some major warnings for this code as it has some serious problems - you do have warnings enabled, I hope ?

Comment: Please read this: http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ and this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

You are passing `&maximum_cycle[MAX_NUMERO]` to `hallarNumeroCirclo` and `Maximo` which is a **single** integer pointer! This is due to the array indexing selecting one, and then you take the address of that.

However, the type required by the functions is an array, when you try to write it would write
to unknown/unmapped area hence SIGSEGVing your program.

Your problem is effectively that the functions except a pointer to pointers, while you pass it a pointer. Note, that the space allocated for an array of pointers might be smaller, than the actual integer array. On x86 they are the same, but here your problem is that your code writes bogus stuff to your pointers and dereferencing the next pointer will crash you.

Try to use `&maximum_cycle` instead of `&maximum_cycle[MAX_NUMERO]` in your source.

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
int  maximum_cycle[MAX_NUMERO];
```

declares an `int` array named `maximum_cycle` with `MAX_NUMERO` elements.

Doing this

```
hallarNumeroCiclo(x,y,&maximum_cycle[MAX_NUMERO]);
```

passes down to the called function the adress of the `MAX_NUMERO + 1` element of array `maximum_cycle`. In C arrays are `0`-based, that us `[0]` addresses he 1st element.

---

```
hallarNumeroCiclo(int x,int y,int *maximum_cycle[MAX_NUMERO]);
```

expects a pointer to (the address of) an `int` array of `MAX_NUMERO` elements, so call the function like this:

```
hallarNumeroCiclo(x,y,&maximum_cycle);
```

Inside `hallarNumeroCiclo` you correctly undestood to have `maximum_cycle` deferenced before you can use it as array. However the `[]`-operator binds tighter then the `*`-operator, that's why this line

```
*maximum_cycle[y-x]=n;
```

is wrong and ought to look like this:

```
(*maximum_cycle)[y-x]=n;
```